# Can two consecutive memory_order_release stores on the same thread be reordered with each other?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

Can two consecutive `memory_order_release` stores on the same thread be reordered with each other? Either from the perspective of the same thread or a different thread loading them?

The [documentation on CPP reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) says:

> A store operation with this memory order performs the release
>   operation: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered
>   after this store.

So in this example:

```
std::atomic<uint64_t> a;
std::atomic<uint64_t> b;

// ...

a.store(0xDEADBEFF, std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
b.store(0xBEEFDEAD, std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
```

I would expect that the `a` store cannot be reordered *after* the `b` store. However maybe the `b` store can still be reordered *before* the `a` store, which would be equivalent? I'm not sure how to read the language.

Put another way: the documentation seems to say the `a` store can't be moved down. Does it also guarantee `b` can't be moved up?

I am trying to determine if on another thread I acquire `b` and see `0xBEEFDEAD` and then acquire `a` if I am guaranteed to see `a` is `0xDEADBEEF`.

Comment: How could that be possible?

Comment: @curiousguy: I'm not sure if it's as if there are two types of reordering, one where you move things up and another where you move things down, and we are only prohibiting moving `a` below `b` and not prohibiting moving `b` above `a`, or if the language covers both ways of looking at it.

Comment: The std does not even mention "reordering". It's just an explanation tool.

Comment: @curiousguy well it has left the explanation ambiguous ;)

Comment: Also, quite incomplete. Real issues of visibility and completeness of memory operations on real CPUs are not always even possibly explained in term of a change in order of asm instructions (or primitive parts of these instr) that happened to be "reordered" around each other. Consider multiple threads that each do only one atomic operation: there is no "reordering" but there are possible ordering issues.

Comment: @curiousguy (deleted) see more correct phrasing in question

Comment: Short answer: release semantic **works**

Comment: @curiousguy sorry, that doesn't clarify anything for me

Comment: BTW "_no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this store._" isn't even correct in general as f.ex. modifications of variables that aren't shared could be reordered (no other thread would see it). It's a low level approach to thread explanation that looks more wrong the more I think about it. (Also, a release store operation on an atomic that isn't shared w/ any other thread does not order anything by definition. Which is a very uninteresting special case.)

Comment: Our "memory order" page is at best "lies we tell to children". It could use some work.

Comment: What I wrote above "_modifications of variables that aren't shared could be reordered_" is self evident (for anyone who doesn't know anything about threads) for anything that isn't visible outside the current function, as compilers (like GCC) don't see a call to an external function as a compiler barrier: `local_var=1; extern_call();` can be reordered at compile time by common compilers. So no "barrier" in `extern_call();` could cancel that due to separate compilation. So the first part of my remark above was very trivial.

Comment: @JosephGarvin "_that doesn't clarify_" works means there is no room for playing w/ words to break stuff by interpreting "reordering" in half back ways

Comment: if **b** be reorder before **a** in current thread, the *a.store* will be **after** *b.store* in current thread, but *a.store* can not be reorder after *b.store*

Comment: @T.C. My answer has two parts; the 2nd part describes a few ways the claim is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion of reordering of memory operations (like reads and writes) is often used to make the issues of inter thread memory visibility more "concrete", as reordering tasks is an every day issue for any person that has blocked and unblocked things to do. But it isn't the basis of inter thread communication and memory visibility. And by the way the `memory_order_x` values are about visibility not "order". Don't use the term "memory order"!

Release semantic is defined by a *promise to any thread that can see the stored value*. (That is why release is only a property of a modification of shared variable; a read of an atomic object, even with `memory_order_seq_cst` memory visibility, could never be a release operation.)

A thread that sees the written value of a release operation can assume that previous operations are "finished". These operations on shared objects that have to be "finished" are the reads and writes and also the other stuff like construction of an object (which your source forgot to mention). Operations that were done "before" (previously in program execution order, or even in a different thread, transitively with the same "finished" property) can be seen as done by a thread that does a read acquire on the written value. (If you did a relaxed read, you can use an acquire barrier afterward to get acquire read semantic.)

It's important to note that the release and acquire operations are bounds and determine the mutual exclusion of operations, like with a mutex: the atomic object is used to obtain mutual exclusion between the written thread and the read thread.

```
a.store(0xDEADBEFF, std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
```

The store of `a` doesn't have to have any specific visibility as there is no previous memory operation (assuming we are at beginning of parallelism) to make visible.

```
b.store(0xBEEFDEAD, std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
```

That one release operation (on `b`) is important: the reason why the compiler can't "reorder" stuff is because other threads can read `b` (which isn't a thread private variable) and could see the specific value `0xBEEFDEAD` and possibly conclude that the release occurred, and use acquire semantic to *guarantee mutual exclusion* of:

- stuff before the store release
- stuff after the load acquire

That is, only if the user code checks that the value was written, and only if the value could come from there. So essentially the user code implements the mutual exclusion protocol, but in the end the compiler makes it work.

---

Regarding the quote:

> The documentation on CPP reference says:
>
> A store operation with this memory order performs the release
>   operation: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered
>   after this store.

I can easily give at least three cases where the reordering is allowed.

The first and most obvious one is a reorder that is always done with function calls by compilers: a modification of a purely local variable not accessible from anywhere else and an external call. That is obviously not even preventable by a specific call like a barrier, as it's a general transformation.

The others are transformations that can't be made with an external function call, but atomic operations are known by the compiler unlike calls to separately compiled functions:

- any action of a strictly function local thread communication primitive, be it a mutex or atomic variable, can be reordered with anything as no other thread can observe or interact with the variable;
- when an atomic object A is manipulated in such way that the compiler can see all operations on it, if the value stored is never changed (it retains its original value), then any operation on another object can be reordered for example with a release store on A.

These might be pretty uninteresting and silly (who uses a mutex as a local variable?) special cases, but they logically exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
// T1
a.store(0xDEADBEFF, std::memory_order::relaxed); // #1
b.store(0xBEEFDEAD, std::memory_order::release); // #2

// T2
if (b.load(std::memory_order::acquire) == 0xBEEFDEAD) {      // #3
   assert(a.load(std::memory_order::relaxed) == 0xDEADBEEF); // #4
}
```

1 is sequenced before 2. 2 synchronizes with 3, and 3 is sequenced before 4. That means 1 happens before 4. By [intro.races]p18, assuming that there are no other modifications to `a`, 4 must take its value from 1, i.e., the assert will never fire.

Comment: By never fire you mean never call abort?

Comment: When you say 1 is sequenced before 2, is this because of release or just the semicolon?

Comment: Just the semicolon.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: If 2. were also relaxed, it would still be *sequenced* after 1 (by the semicolon), but it couldn't synchronize-with an acquire load from *another* thread.  i.e. you'd be missing the "A synchronizes with X" part for creating an "inter-thread happens before":  http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-9.3.1

Comment: @JosephGarvin: Separately, if 1. was release and 2. was relaxed, you'd still be screwed.  Release is only a 1-way barrier, and doesn't make sure that later operations can't become visible before it.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/.  (i.e. on a real CPU, a release store can sit around in the store buffer until after later loads and even stores become globally visible, if those later stores are not also release.  Of course in C++ compile-time reordering is also allowed, not just runtime, but it can be a useful mental model sometimes.)